# Mobile webpage using location services - give user native link to setting when location services are off

Tags: javascript, php, android, iphone

We have some location based searches that utilizes the users latitude and longitude.  First it attempts to get the lat/long based on the IP as a fall-back, like this:

```
// get lat and long based on users ip address
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$location = json_decode($output);
curl_close($ch);

$ip_latitude = $location->latitude;
$ip_longitude = $location->longitude;
```

But since that isn't super accurate in many cases, we then use the user geocode based on the device, which looks like this:

```
    function myfunction () {

    // check if geolocation is available
            x = navigator.geolocation;
            x.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);

    // if available, set variables in the form for lat/long and autofill the search box with 'current location'

            function success(position){
                document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById('input-box-field1').value = 'Current Location';
            }

// if not available, then fall back to IP geocode for the form variables as well as give the user an alert that their location services aren't on.
            function failure()
            {
                document.getElementById('latitude').value = <?php echo $ip_latitude;;?>;
                document.getElementById('longitude').value = <?php echo $ip_longitude;?>;
                alert("Your location services are off.  Using an approximate location.");
                document.getElementById('input-box-field1').value = 'Current Location';
            }

    }
```

This is all working great, however, when the user's location services aren't on, I'd like for the alert to be a more native option that also give the user a link to their settings on their iphone or andriod so they could turn location service on easily.

I assume this may be different code for andriod and iphone and I don't know where to start to get this link to their settings.

Thanks in advance for any help in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `navigator.geolocation` object is standardized, and [present on all recent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation). Therefore you can simply check for its existence.

```
var showPos = function(position) { alert(position.coords); console.log(position.coords); }

if (navigator.geolocation)
 { navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos); }
else
  { alert("Noooo!"); }
```

Note that `getCurrentPosition` is an “asynchronous” call, i.e. it doesn't return a result right away, instead it expects a callback which it will call as soon as it was able to retrieve a position.

w3scools has a more sophisticated example with error handling: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error